# ParsedJSON.splice() splices every second item

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that is supposed to remove every json item if something, but instead removes every second one. Data is parsed json:

```
    {
      "idArticle": "1",
      "language": "SK"
    },
    {
      "idArticle": "2",
      "language": "SK"
    },
    {
      "idArticle": "3",
      "language": "SK"
    },
    {
      "idArticle": "4",
      "language": "SK"
    }
```

If we run this through my function (with let lang="x"), it removes items with ids 1 3 and keeps 2 and 4. Instead of splicing it all.

```
    function cutArticleList(data) {
        for (i in data) {
            if (data[i].language === lang.toUpperCase()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                data.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        res.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: So consider that when you splice out elements, you are adjusting the array that you are iterating over.  This is one of the "do not do" things with relation to iterators.  You should not be modifying the thing you iterate upon.

Comment: Consider using `filter` instead?

Comment: ↑ filter, or do a normal `for` loop that iterates from array.size -1 to 0

Comment: Thank you for explaining @Taplar, I used filter and now it works